# How to run Python Code in mininet

Tags: python, network-programming, emulation, executable, mininet

I write a simple topology with Python in mininet, but I dont know how to execute  my code,I searched in internet and find several methods.
which one is correct? And what is the difference between them?

1. Method 1:

   ```
   sudo mn --custom ~/mininet/custom/filename.py --topo mytopo
   ```
2. Method 2:

   ```
   sudo phython filename.py
   ```
3. Method 3:

   ```
   chmod u+x filename.py
   sudo ./filename.py
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Method 1** is the classical method to deploy a custom topology in Mininet. You can specify in the same command the controller, like this :

  ```
  sudo mn --custom ~/mininet/custom/filename.py --topo mytopo --controller=remote,ip=[CONTROLLER_IP],port=6633
  ```

  or if you don't, Mininet will use the default.
- **Method 2** executes the `[FILENAME]` file. Note that here *you have to specify the controller* which you will use ***inside the python script***. This is the difference with Method 1.
- **Method 3** makes the `[FILENAME]` file executable with the first command, and then executes it. It is the same as Method 2.